# Xcode storyboard - constraint greater or equal not working

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I have this settings:

[image]

In XCode interface builder, I have added constraints. Now the red one between "S...gs" button and right "large" button is set to "greater than or equal", but it gives me error about missing constraint for position X. If I cnage this constraint to "equal" error is gone. What is wrong here?

EDIT:
Maybe its "conflicting" with some other constrains I have. I am adding full storyboard settings for the view controller

(Plus there are also some "programatically" added constraints during execution, but those should not affect XCode storyboard)

[image]

Comment: which one have to change either small or large button?

Comment: @DSDharma the large one should increase / descrease its size based on content

Comment: try to set set 2 small buttons width constant less than or equal.Of course if those 2 small button width is static constant then probably it through error

Comment: give fix width constraint to any one small view .

Comment: Both small button have width constraint set to 48

Comment: did you give greater than equal constraint to all view or only large view ?

Comment: @KKRocks only to large view

Comment: it is working fine my scenarion . i have applied constraints as below . small First-> L,Trailing,W,Top small Second -> Trailing,Top,Bottom,Width , LargeView -> Trailing,Top,Bottom,Greter than equal width .

Comment: where you are assigned fix width constraint to small views ?

Answer (score 4):

Add both the constraints in storyboard (equal to & greater than or equal to). And check the option "Remove at build time" for the **equal to** constraint
[image: Check here]

Answer (score 1):

An inequality constraint is not enough for Auto Layout to know exactly where to place your wide button. As I can see, you haven't specified neither a trailing constraint nor a width constraint for your wide button, so Auto Layout does not know where to put it. Try adding a trailing constraint from the wide button to the superview and you should get what you want.

Comment: I have trailing for wide button set to Superview.Trailing

Comment: @MartinPerry, please post the other constraints that you have defined so I can see the whole picture. :-)

Comment: Hmm, strange, there's nothing wrong in your setup. When I reconstructed it in my storyboard, Auto Layout doesn't complain about anything. Maybe you can try deleting the constraints that relate to the buttons and re-adding them again

Comment: I have tried it in another project and it worked fine. Also on device, it seems to be wogking as expected... wtf

Answer (score 1):

As it shown up, there is no real error. Xcode reports it as an error, but at runtime on a real device it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set search button width constraint to greater or equal to 0